# No visualization of the dependency graph when running a Luigi workflow

Tags: python, luigi

I have recently started to use Luigi. When I run a workflow, all task would show up on the Task List but the Dependency Graph shows only an empty frame:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ah, just figured out it only shows the dependency graph for particular tasks, not for the whole workflow. So, I had to select a task to see the dependency graph.